# Why does using $f(x)=x^2$ not work in Pollard's rho algorithm?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring, computational-mathematics

In Pollard's rho algorithm for integer factorization, we use pseudorandom sequences of the form $x_{i+1}=f(x_i)$ and look at them$\mod{n}$ until we get a cycle. Utilizing the birthday paradox, we can expect a cycle$\mod{n}$ in $O(\sqrt{n})$ steps.
Typical polynomials that are used are $f(x)=x^2+1$ and $f(x)=x^2-1$.

My question is - why isn't $f(x)=x^2$ used? Is it not random enough$\mod{n}$? And if so, why is that?

Comment: I am not an expert in this algorithm , but I think it is better to use irreducible polynomials.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ can be taken as shown in the animation in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm).